# Using the FFT to multiply two binary numbers

Tags: python, fft

I'm completeing an assignment but a little stuck on part 5 and 6. It essentially does: Using the FFT to multiply two binary numbers. I was wondering if someone could help out.

```
# The binary numbers and their product
a_bin = 0b100100100100
b_bin = 0b111000111000
c_bin = a_bin * b_bin
print('The product of a and b is', c_bin)


# (i) The coefficients of the polynomials A and B
Acoeff = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
Bcoeff = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]


# (ii) the value representations of A and B
Aval = np.fft(Acoeff, 32)
Bval = np.fft(Bcoeff, 32)


# (iii) The value representation of C
Cval = []
for i in range(len(Aval)):
    Cval.append(Aval[i] * Bval[i])

print(Cval)
# (iv) The coefficients of the polynomial C
Ccoeff = np.ifft(Cval)
# we'll get rid of the imaginary parts, which are just numerical errors
for i, c in enumerate(Ccoeff):
    Ccoeff[i] = int(round(c.real))


# (v) calculate the product by evaluating the polynomial at 2, i.e., C(2)
# (You may need to take the real part at the end if there is a small imaginary component)
prod = 0
print('Using the FFT the product of a and b is', int(round(prod.real)))


# (vi) write code to calculate the binary digits of c directly from the coefficients of C, Ccoeff.
# hint:  You can use (q,r) = divmod(x, 2) to find the quotient and remainder of x when divided by 2
```

Comment: that code is not properly indented. Since indentation is critical in Python, please fix that.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused. Are you sure that's the assignment? An FFT *needs* the capability to multiply numbers internally, so using it to create a multiplication is... unusual. In fact, the FFT is often used to replace a convolution in time domain by a multiplication in frequency domain; but you'd still have to do the multiplication yourself (the FFT doesn't help with that).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Large number multiplication can be done with FFT (although more often with number-theoretic transforms) and is the basis for the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm)

Comment: @SleuthEye I know; point is that considering the "oldschool manual multiplication algorithm, multiplication behaves a lot like convolution; trying to trigger OP's problem solving abilities here.